# Shematics of the BeMicro CV eval board from Arrow

Tags: intel-fpga, cyclone, dev-kit

Where can I find the complete schematics of the board?

Arrow sells an ultra low cost FPGA platform with a Cyclone V device on it for around 30$.
Ok, for that price it has the bear minimum: 2 buttons, 8 LEDs, several connectors, a flash memory, a DDR3, power supplies, SD card slot, etc...

This is just fine for getting started and learning basic FPGA design.

But, the only datasheet I can find is the following : [official schematics link](http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2013/9/23/0/52/45/310/arrowd_/manual/c__users_kevinc1_appdata_local_temp_bemicro_cv_f23_201305151.pdf)

Unfortunately, this document does not include the whole board. Some part of it, such as the MAX V CPLD, the FTDI USB chip as well as some connectors are not included. Do one of you has access to the complete schematics? If yes, is it possible to share it?

I do understand that the MAX V part is the included debugger/programmer. But what I do not understand is: why keeping this hidden?:

- We have access to the full gerber files, thus it's easy BUT VERY TIME CONSUMING, to redraw the full schematics (except for the exact passive component values, but it's not rocket science here...).
- The real IP that has to remain proprietary and hidden is the CPLD configuration, not the routing around it!

It would be interesting to know how the USB is connected to the FTDI, and if we can use it as a communication channel to a PC software. I know that I can use a virtual JTAG debugging channel to do this, but there might be other ways. By keeping this part hidden I just have no idea of what I can do.

A better approach would have been to keep the MAX V code secret, but disclose the complete schematics. I would still consider the MAX V as a black box with proprietary magics inside, but I would be able to use my eval board the way I want to.

Comment: One of the things you give up on the lowest-priced evaluation/development boards is access to the propriety programming hardware. If you're designing a custom board, you wouldn't ordinarily include the programming hardware anyway. You'd use a separate programmer attached through a header of some sort.

Comment: just do a quick search for the Altera USB blaster and you will find both the schematic and the source for the CPLD online.